# Proper use of Repository pattern. Should return multiple entity types or only one?

Tags: c#, architecture, repository-pattern

My coworker is writing this code and from as I understand he should only have methods that return one or many of type USER. I would think in another layer of abstraction you would combine the entities as needed but in the repository if its a USER repository then you only return USER(s) … What is correct?

```
  public interface IUserRepository: IAsyncRepository<User>
{
     Task<IReadOnlyList<User>> GetAllApproversAsync();
     Task<IReadOnlyList<User>> GetAllSubmittersAsync();
     Task<IReadOnlyList<User>> GetAllAdminsAsync();
     Task<User> GetByIdWithUserRolesAsync(int id);
     Task<List<Role>> GetRolesforUserByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<List<UserRole>> GetUserRolesforUserByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<UserRole> GetSubmitterUserRoleforUserByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<UserRole> GetApproverUserRoleforUserByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<UserRole> GetAdminUserRoleforUserByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<List<User>> GetDefaultSubmittersforUserByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<List<User>> GetDefaultManagersforUserByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<List<OwnerMembership>> GetOwnerMembershipsForSubmitterRoleByUserIdAsync(int userId);
     Task<List<OwnerMembership>> GetOwnerMembershipsForApproverRoleByUserIdAsync(int userId);

}
```

Comment: It's subjective and there is no single right answer. What does `IAsyncRepository` define? Maybe this interface is just poorly named?

Comment: It depends. Now there is a trend of creating repositories per business category or whatever.

At the end, if you use an ORM like EF or NHibernate, they are actually repositories, right?

Some links about this using a quick search:
https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/
https://dotnetcultist.com/repository-pattern-dead-with-entity-framework/
https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're absolutely correct. The UserRepository should return only user(s). This code returns so many things. You better to create another service to retrieve those things. But don't put everything into 1 class. That just break the Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: I feel like this answer was accepted purely because it agrees with the OPs opinion. The question was closed because any answer will be opinion-based rather than canonically correct.

Comment: When it comes to design, I think most of them are opinion. There is no true/false in designing a class. That's why we need design principle to help correcting our design. And again, how we understand the principle is opinion. To me, a class that exceeds 500 lines is not good, but you can be fine with it. No one wrong or right.

Comment: I thought there was a standard way to use the repo pattern that wasn't based on opinion so that is why I asked here